# Is it possible to run/manage/modify the functionality of a program fully within Python?

Tags: python

I have a basic program (a .exe file which sources from another .exe file and multiple .dll files) which I want to manage (using this word for lack of a better term) within Python. This program takes a text file as input, the user manually clicks a few buttons, and the program outputs a few lines of text based on the contents of the text file. However, this output is only displayed within the interface of the program.

Is there a way to to "manage" the program within Python such that Python inputs the text file, runs the program, and outputs the 'few lines of text' as a separate text file versus the current state of just visually displaying it within the program? Basically I want Python to "encapsulate" the program and take over all functions of the program in order to modify their functionality while using the existing base files of the program.

Is this possible? Could anyone point me in the right direction regarding the terminology, etc? The only method I currently know is to have Python take over the manual clicking within the program, but I want something with no visual display such that the Python script is taking over all functionality of the program.

Comment: I would start with investigating https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto